# php: issue with pass values to parameter

Tags: php

option 1:

```
<?php 
function hookRequest($func, $params = array()){
    var_dump($func);
    var_dump($params);
}

hookRequest('func1', array('param1', 'param2'));
```

option 2:

```
<?php 
function hookRequest($func, $params){
    var_dump($func);
    var_dump($params);
}

hookRequest('func1', array('param1', 'param2'));
```

Question:

Both of above scripts can work. But I saw some scripts use this way: `$params = array()`, so just want to find out what is the difference between `$params = array()` and `$params` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't pass anything into option1

```
hookRequest('func1');
```

then the $params is now an empty array.

```
function foobar($something,$foo = 'var')
{
   var_dump($something,$foo);
}

foobar('something');
```

Output:

```
string(9) "something" string(3) "var"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on the "Function Arguments" basics in

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that option 1 makes the second parameter optional, so that you can leave out the second option and the default value will be given to $param.

Option 2 makes the second parameter required, and will return a warning if you don't provide at least two parameters, e.g.

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for hookRequest
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called [default parameters in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

When you declare your function, `hookRequest($func, $params = array()){...` the `$paramas = array()` tell it to set it as an array when the passed parameter is blank.